# ASP.NET Web Project from local IIS, exclude virtual directory from publish

Tags: asp.net, deployment, virtual-directory, vs-web-site-project

I had a file system only web project solution. I needed to convert it to use IIS, so I mapped a site in IIS to the path where the solution existed.

In Visual Studio, I opened the solution from local IIS Site, and everything is great.

Except now, when I publish the solution (to deploy to another webserver),
it makes full copies of the virtual directories.

I do not need these as physical copies, obviously the point of a virtual directory is to point to an already existing path somewhere.

Comment: What kind of deployment are you using? if there is already an existing directory you can just use File system in the Publish method and not a web deploy.

Comment: I am using Publish Website from the Build Menu within Visual Studios.
Then I copy that published Directory up to the webserver.

Comment: Note: This is a web site project, not a web application.  It seems I do not have as many options this way, but I cannot change to a web application due to other developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in IIS you click on the virtual Directory and click convert to application.

Visual Studio will no longer build or publish that virtuqal directory (now applciation).

You do not need to convert your web site project to a web application project, or go through anything more complicated.

Of note: I was having trouble with the CFIDE virtual directory, as this site is also using coldfusion for some other pre-built parts.

Converting CFIDE from a virtual directory to an application has had no affect on Coldfusion, nor any files inside the native CFIDE directory.